# HtmlAnchor won't execute href that using javascript

Tags: java, htmlunit

I wanted to execute an Anchor using `.click()` method by getting the Anchor using `getAnchorByHref` that contains javascript code to go to another page. Here's my snippet below. But running this code gives me.

`ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[a] attributeName=[href] attributeValue=[javascript:submit('ActivityForm.jsp')]`

```
try{

   HtmlPage currentPage = client.getWebClient().getPage("url");
   HtmlAnchor createOrder = (HtmlAnchor) currentPage.getAnchorByHref("javascript:submit('ActivityForm.jsp')");
   createOrder.click();

}
catch(FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you pls post the html code of the anchor tag also

Answer (score 1):

As the ElementNotFoundException says: the element you are looking for was not found on the page. There might be various reasons for that

- there is no anchor element with this javascipt (comparison is done using equals so his is case sensitive and white space sensitive)
- the element was added after the page loading by some javascript. In this case you have to wait for the javascripts jobs after getting the page and before start searching for the anchor
- maybe there is an error in HtmlUnit

If you provide a public url we can have a look at your case.

Comment: My guess is that one of the first two is the case.